# Scala automatic getter and setter overwriting with custom _=

Tags: class, scala, overriding, setter, getter

In scala there is no difference for the user of a class between calling a method or accessing some field/member directly using val x = myclass.myproperty. To be able to control e.g. setting or getting a field, scala let us override the _= method. But is = really a method? I am confused.

Let's take the following code:

```
class Car(var miles: Int)

var myCar = new Car(10)
println(myCar.miles) //prints 10
myCar.miles = 50
println(myCar.miles) //prints 50
```

Same goes for this code (notice the double space in `myCar.miles  = 50`):

```
class Car(var miles: Int)

var myCar = new Car(10)
println(myCar.miles) //prints 10
myCar.miles  = 50
println(myCar.miles) //still prints 50
```

Now i want to change the way how the `miles` can be set or read, e.g. always printing something on the screen. How can i do this so that the users of my class are not affected and also so that it does not make any difference if whitespaces are used before the = sign?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Car(private var _miles: Int) {
  def miles = _miles
  def miles_=(m: Int): Unit = {
    println("boo")
    _miles = m
  }
}
```

Whitespace is not significant. The compiler sees you're assigning `miles` and will insert a call to `miles_=` no matter how many spaces you insert.

Comment: So does that mean, if i declare a method with name miles_= and with name mil_es then miles_= is not the name but is specially interpreted by scala where mil_es is a regular function name (where _ has no special meaning)? If so, that means i cant create a MyClass.something_=() method because _ is already interpreted as any positive number of _?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Only the `_=` suffix has a special meaning. You can also call the `miles_=` method by its full name — it just looks ugly.

Comment: @Jean-Phillippe Pellet, that means i cannot create to different methods for `miles =` and `miles_=` so the namespace is restricted. I just wanted to make sure that i got it right.

Comment: Still don't get your point. How does this “restrict the namespace”?

Comment: Because you can't use all allowed characters for method names on each position giving every method a different behaviour. That is if course not practical relevant but it's also not very sophisticated in my eyes.

Comment: You **are** allowed to use all allowed characters for your method names. You must just know that declaring a `var` also declares the two accessor methods that go with it.