# What construct should I use to 'intercept' any getter/setter call to a user-defined class?

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble finding a way to achieve the following goal: I want to intercept the getter/setter invocations on any user-defined class. Example:

```
class Foo(var bar: String) {
 // ...
}


val foo = new Foo("hi")
foo.bar // how to intercept this?
foo.bar = "hello" // idem
```

Imagine I want to log the amount of times the bar field was accessed and/or changed. How can I implement this without using AOP? Also, the user-defined class can not be changed to define custom getters/setters.

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s07.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala automatic getter and setter overwriting with custom \_=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935138/scala-automatic-getter-and-setter-overwriting-with-custom)

Comment: Not a duplicate as I am looking for a way to achieve that behaviour without changing the implementation of the user-defined class (in my case Foo).

Comment: You mean you can't change the code of `Foo`, and you can't change the code that uses `Foo`? Then I can only think of reflection that changes the implementation of `Foo` without touching the source.

Comment: @Bergi Yes it seems that I'll need to use reflection. Do you have any idea whether or not it is possible to change method behaviour (in my case that of the setters) using reflection?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible with reflection.